# Python dictionary error

Tags: python

In the below code d_arr is an array of dictionaries

```
 def process_data(d_arr):
    flag2 = 0
    for dictionaries in d_arr:  
      for k in dictionaries:
        if ( k == "*TYPE" ):
          """ Here we determine the type """
          if (dictionaries[k].lower() == "name"):
            dictionaries.update({"type" : 0})
            func = name(dictionaries)
            continue
          elif (dictionaries[k].lower() == "ma"):
            dictionaries.update({"type" : 1})
            func = DCC(dictionaries)
            logging.debug(type(func))
           continue
```

When the above is done i get an error saying

```
               for k in dictionaries:
            RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
           2010-08-02 05:26:44,167 DEBUG Returning
```

Is this forbidden to do something like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, indeed, forbidden.  Moreover, you don't really need a loop over all keys here, given that the weirdly named `dictionaries` appears to be a single dict; rather than the `for k in dictionaries:` (or the workable `for k in dictionaries.keys()` that @Triptych's answer suggests), you could use...:

```
    tp = dictionaries.get('*TYPE')
    if tp is not None:
      """ Here we determine the type """
      if tp.lower() == 'name':
        dictionaries.update({"type" : 0})
        func = name(dictionaries)
      elif tp.lower() == "ma":
        dictionaries.update({"type" : 1})
        func = DCC(dictionaries)
        logging.debug(type(func))
```

This is going to be much faster if `dictionaries` has any considerable length, for you're reaching directly for the one entry you care about, rather than looping over all entries to check each of them for the purpose of seeing if it *is* the one you care about.

Even if you've chosen to omit part of your code, so that after this start the loop on `dictionaries` is *still* needed, I think my suggestion is still preferable because it lets you get any alteration to `dictionaries` done and over with (assuming of course that you don't keep altering it in the hypothetical part of your code I think you may have chosen to omit;-).

Comment: Man how do you find the time? You, like, actually read all the code.

Answer (score 3):

That error is pretty informative; you can't change the size of a dictionary you are currently iterating over.

The solution is to get the keys all at once and iterate over them:

```
# Do this
for k in dictionaries.keys():

# Not this
for k in dictionaries:
```